# How can I view the options for a git command in the console?

Tags: git

Usually I accomplish this by typing in some fake options so that it tells me all the real ones when it sees I clearly don't know what I'm doing.

What's the ACTUAL way to get it to list all the options for a command?

Example of what I do presently:

```
$ git push -aslivuq --fake-flag

error: unknown switch `a'
usage: git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --repo <repository>   repository
    --all                 push all refs
    --mirror              mirror all refs
    --delete              delete refs
    --tags                push tags (can't be used with --
    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    --porcelain           machine-readable output
    -f, --force           force updates
    --force-with-lease[=<refname>:<expect>]
                          require old value of ref to be a
    --recurse-submodules[=<check>]
                          control recursive pushing of sub
    --thin                use thin pack
    --receive-pack <receive-pack>
                          receive pack program
    --exec <receive-pack>
                          receive pack program
    -u, --set-upstream    set upstream for git pull/status
    --progress            force progress reporting
    --prune               prune locally removed refs
    --no-verify           bypass pre-push hook
    --follow-tags         push missing but relevant tags
```

Comment: `git <command> -h` or `git help <command>` for a full man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Brian Roach in the comments:

```
git <command> -h or git help <command> for a full man page.
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean `man git-[command]` ? (e.g. `man git-push`)

Answer (score 0):

You can view the man page by running `man git-<subcommand>` or `git <subcommand> --help`.